# Entity gets moved instead of added

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am stumped on this problem. The behavior I am trying to achieve is for one test to have multiple allowed groups of students assigned. This works correctly, but when I try to assign the same group to multiple tests, it gets moved instead of added. I think the pictures explain it best.

[image: Step 1 - Second test has group "456" in allowed]

[image: Step 2 - I add group "456" to a different test]

[image: Step 3 - The group gets added]

[image: Step 4 - But it disappeared from the test it was in before!]

Here are my models:

```
public class TestParameters
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(60)]
    //in minutes
    //0 = no limit
    [DisplayName("Time Limit")]
    public int TimeLimit { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DefaultValue(10)]
    [DisplayName("Number of Questions")]
    public int NumQuestions { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Open From")]
    public DateTime OpenFrom { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Open To")]
    public DateTime OpenTo { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Allowed Groups")]
    public virtual ICollection<StudentGroup> AllowedGroups { get; set; } 
}

public class StudentGroup
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And the relevant controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewGroup()
{
    var groupCode = Request["groupCode"];
    var paramId = Request["parametersId"];

    var group = db.StudentGroups.Find(groupCode);
    var parameters = db.TestParameters.Find(int.Parse(paramId));

    if (group == null)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "No group with code " + groupCode + " exists.";
    }
    else if (parameters.AllowedGroups.Contains(group))
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "The group with code " + groupCode + " already has access to this test.";
    }
    else
    {
        parameters.AllowedGroups.Add(group);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return View(parameters);
}
```

What can cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks awfully like you have a one-many relationship set up rather than the many-many you describe you need.

You need something like this in your DbContext OnModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{    
    modelBuilder.Entity<TestParameters>()
        .HasMany(x => x.StudentGroup)
        .WithMany(x => x.TestParameters)
    .Map(x =>
    {
        x.ToTable("StudentGroupTestParameter")
        x.MapLeftKey("Id");
        x.MapRightKey("Code");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize I also needed a navigation property to TestParameters in my StudentGroup model.